# Connecting Raspberry Pi to Arduino Leonardo

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, python

Can any Raspberry Pi/Arduino experts tell me what are the best options of sending data from the RPi to a Leonardo given the following:

1. Running Raspbian on the RPi.
2. Running a Python script on the RPi which detects mouse data, movement.
3. Only need to send mouse data to Leonardo.

Comment: On Raspberry pi use directory /home/pi/.arduino15 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plug the Leonardo in to the USB port of the Pi.  Open the serial port /dev/ttyACM0 and send the data.  On the Arduino receive the data through the Serial object.

Alternatively, connect the Pi's TX pin to the Leonardo's RX pin, and connect the Leonardo's TX pin, through a 5V -> 3.3V level shifting circuit (there's lots of options - google them) to the Pi's RX pin, then use /dev/AMA0 instead of /dev/ACM0.

Comment: thanks. if both USB ports are being used is there another option?

Comment: Add a powered USB hub?

Comment: @eco_bach: did you read the "alternatively..."?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen I added that after the comment.

Comment: thanks! will try. By 'level shifting circuit' I assume you mean a logic converter? https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12009

Comment: Anything that will convert a 0-5V signal into a 0-3.3V one.  That would do, yes, but so would 2 resistors.